# PHP - Link img element to PHP file

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to link an `img` element to a php file.

`image.php` handles the img element. This is the code.

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$imgs = array(

    'media/documents/Penguins.jpg',
    'media/documents/Chrysanthemum.jpg',
    );

$createimgs = array();

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $createimgs[] = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
}

foreach ($createimgs as $createimg) {
    imagejpeg($createimg);
}
```

And this is the content of `index.php`

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<img src="image.php?img=1" alt="" title="Picture 1" class="pic">
<img src="image.php?img=2" alt="" title="Picture 2" class="pic">
```

It works but the display of both is `Penguins.jpg`, `Chrysanthemum.jpg` is not displayed.

How can I display `Penguins.jpg` and `Chrysanthemum.jpg` in order?

Any idea would be of help!

Comment: Hey provide more code atleast functions imagecreatefromjpeg() and imagejpeg() which you are using.

Comment: @mamta `imagecreatefromjpeg` and `imagejpeg` are php functions.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Comment: Did you try and set the header? `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`

Comment: @st2erw2od Yes, I tried and set the header. Display of both is still `Penguins.jpg`

Comment: Your script never retrieves the value of `img` from the url. And why do you have loops in this script?

Comment: @Jocelyn I have loops in this script because I want to use multiple images. Retrieving the value of `img` is what I'm missing...

Comment: this code looks like you have not basic understanding of how programming works. start by reading a basic php tutorial on arrays, loops and then the `$_GET` php superglobal

Comment: @Sharky you're correct, I should understand the flow first... I appreciate your feedback.